# Is such code legal?

Tags: c, pointers, standards, c99

I've been using a program, compiled using GCC 4.4.1 (ISO C99) and noticed this quirk today. Although it works on target without any problem neither does compiler emit any warning with -Wall.

```
void mutex_init(mutex_t *mutex)
{
 if(unlikely(mutex->magic == MUTX_MAGIC_CHAR))
    return;

 mutex->owner = NULL;
 mutex->prior = NULL;
 mutex->magic = MUTX_MAGIC_CHAR;
 thread_queue_init(&mutex->queue);
}
```

shouldn't it be like

```
*mutex->owner = NULL;
```

Comment: I don't believe this compiles without warning: the brackets aren't balanced.

Comment: that was copy paste problem.. fixing it now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, `magic->owner` is equivalent to `(*magic).owner`.

The `->` operator is meant to work on pointers to structures, while the `.` operator work on structures directly.